# Undefined is added in a row when dynamically adding row in table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, undefined

When i dynamically adding row in a table using jquery  instead of dynamically inserted data , undefined is being added in table row  .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eLyT.jpg)
This is the form , when i am adding data , instead of data it is adding undefined.

```
var employee = {
        ID: 0,
        Name: "",
        LastName: ""
    };

    function addEmployee(employee)
    {
        debugger;
        alert(employee.ID);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:51640/employee/createemployee",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:
               "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(employee),
            success: function (employee) {                    
                employeeAddSuccess(employee);
            },                           
        });
    }



    function employeeAddSuccess(employee) {
        alert(employee.Name);           
        employeeAddRow(employee);            
        alert("about to clear ");
        formClear();
        alert("successfully addded");
    }

    function employeeAddRow(employee) {
        alert(employee.ID);
        $("#employeeTable tbody").append(employeeBuildTableRow(employee));
    }
    function formClear() {
        $("#lblempID").val("");
        $("#lblEmpName").val("");
        $("#lblEmpLastName").val("");
    }
    function addClick() {
        formClear();
    }

    function employeeBuildTableRow(employee) {
        debugger;
        var ret =
          "<tr>" +
           "<td>" + employee.ID + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + employee.Name + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + employee.LastName + "</td>" +
          "</tr>";
        alert(ret);
        return ret;
    }


    function updateClick() {
        // Build product object from inputs
        employee = new Object();
        employee.ID = $('#lblempID').val();
        employee.Name = $('#lblEmpName').val();
        employee.LastName = $('#lblEmpLastName').val();
        addEmployee(employee);           
    }
```

Comment: what is the format of employee coming back into success method? Have you tried to see if it has value or is it null?

Comment: Show us your html please, it seems you employee object dont have any data in it

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to $.ajax options. This will work if your backend code is returning correct data

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't stringify the data you're sending, try :

```
function addEmployee(employee)
    {
        debugger;
        console.log(employee);  // verify the data that will be sent to the server
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:51640/employee/createemployee",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json'
            contentType:
               "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: employee,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result); // verify the result coming back                  
                employeeAddSuccess(result);
            },
            fail: function (error) {
                console.log(error); // if there's an error, log that too
            }
        });
}
```

you should also log what happens on the server when it receives the data, it is probably where the 'undefined' happens.

I am assuming that you also need error handling server side to get a meaningful result in the `fail` callback of your ajax call. The code above should help you flag where the problem comes from.

And finally, for the love of everything code, do not use alerts for debugging! console.log works just as well and won't block your application/annoy the hell out of everyone involved :)